# Transferring files modified in the last 10 minutes from S3 to Big Query using Big Query Data Transfer Service

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

On Big Query's Data Transfer Service [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer-intro#consistency_considerations) for S3, it states:

> To reduce the possibility of missing data, schedule your Amazon S3 transfers to occur at least 10 minutes after your files are added to the bucket.

By default, when running a transfer, the logs says that it only transfers files that have a last modified time of 10 minutes ago.

However, based on the documentation, it seems that there is a way to modify this setting. When I create a transfer (whether in console or in Java), I can't seem to find a way to make it transfer files are less than 10 minutes old. How to do it?